# Ошибка java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0. Прошу помогите

Tags: android

Выводит ошибку: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

```
if(newsfeed.attachments.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < newsfeed.attachments.size(); i++) {

            if (newsfeed.attachments.get(i).type.equals("link")) { // вот эта строка
                View to_add;
                post_audio_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                final CardView post_link_view;
                TextView title, url;
                to_add = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.link_post_item, null);

                post_link_view = to_add.findViewById(R.id.postLinkView);
                title = to_add.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
                url = to_add.findViewById(R.id.linkUrl);

           }
      }
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104380/discussion-on-question-by-filvin--java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-ind).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Код лучше заменить на следующий

```
for (Класс attachment: newsfeed.attachments) {
    if ("link".equals(attachment.type)) { // вот эта строка
        View to_add;
        post_audio_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final CardView post_link_view;
        TextView title, url;
        to_add = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.link_post_item, null);

        post_link_view = to_add.findViewById(R.id.postLinkView);
        title = to_add.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        url = to_add.findViewById(R.id.linkUrl);
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ^^

Comment: Не понимаю. `foreach` - это то же самое, что и `fori`. Чисто синтаксический сахар. Почему ошибка исчезла?

Comment: Не то же самое: если правый аргумент реализует интерфейс `Iterable`, то `foreach` перебирает элементы итератором.